# Perl: how to replace extended characters by their corresponding entity in an XML file?

Tags: perl

In an XML file, I need to convert all characters above character code 127 to their corresponding literal entity (typically convert `é` into `&#xe9;`).

Here is what I wrote, but it doesn't work.

```
sub as_entity{
  my $char = shift;
  return sprintf("&#x%.4x;", ord($char));
}

sub entitify{
  my $str = shift;
  $str =~ s/([\x7f-\x{ffffff}])/(?{as_entity($1)})/g;
  return $str;
}
```

It seems I can't use the `(?{...})` in the replacement part...

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `(?{...})` is a regex atom. It cannot be used outside of regex patterns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$str =~ s/([\x7f-\x{ffffff}])/as_entity($1)/ge;
```

should be enough. (Note the extra [`/e`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace) modifier.)

Comment: Should be `\x80` rather than `\x7F` to match the OP's spec. I'd write it as `[^\x00-\x7F]`

Comment: @ikegami: I didn't touch that part of the regex, and I believe the `\x7f` is "correct" - that's the DEL char, which should probably be escaped.

Comment: @ikegami : you're right, although the delete character (charcode 127) is as well being escaped too, my description wasn't exactly accurate about that. Thanks for mentioning anyway.

Comment: @subtenante, By that logic, 00-1F except 09, 0A and 0D should be escaped too.